# Target Labeling Using Sliding Window On Stock Data In Python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, algorithmic-trading

I'm trying to label **BUY**, **SELL**, and **HOLD** values to the closing stock prices based on the algorithm I found in a paper. I'm not quite able to figure out the error I'm getting. I'd very much appreciate your help. Thank you.

**Algorigthm:**

[image: Algorithm]

**[EDITED]**

**My implementation:**

```
window_size = 11
counter = 0
result = []

window_begin_idx=0; window_end_idx=0; window_middle_idx=0; min_idx=0; max_idx=0;

while counter < len(closing_price):
    if counter > window_size:

        window_begin_idx = counter - window_size
        window_end_idx = window_begin_idx + window_size - 1
        window_middle_idx = (window_begin_idx + window_end_idx)//2
        
        for i in range(window_begin_idx, window_end_idx+1):
            rng = closing_price[window_begin_idx:window_end_idx+1]
            number = closing_price[i]
            mins = rng.min()
            maxs = rng.max()
            if number < mins:
                mins=number
                min_idx = np.argmin(rng)
            if number > maxs:
                maxs=number
                max_idx = np.argmax(rng)

        if max_idx == window_middle_idx:
            result.append("SELL")
        elif min_idx == window_middle_idx:
            result.append("BUY")
        else:
            result.append("HOLD")
         
        mins = 0.0
        maxs = 10000.0
    counter+=1
```

After the edit based on the author's `JAVA` code, I'm only getting the **HOLD** label. The author's implementation is [here](https://github.com/omerbsezer/CNN-TA/blob/master/Phase1.java).

Comment: What makes you think that the first one is Java code?

Comment: The file name has `.java` extension

Comment: okay, got it. but i don't think people that follow the Java tag will necessarily be able/ interested to help you with a Python question. the pseudo code is more than enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading through the author's implementation and following the suggestions provided by MBo, I have managed to solve this issue. So, now anyone who wants this algorithm in `python`, below is the code:

```
window_size = 11
counter = 0
result = []
 
window_begin_idx=0; window_end_idx=0; window_middle_idx=0; min_idx=0; max_idx=0; 
number=0.0; mins=10000.0; maxs=0.0

while counter < len(closing_price):
    if counter > window_size:
        window_begin_idx = counter - window_size
        window_end_idx = window_begin_idx + window_size - 1
        window_middle_idx = (window_begin_idx + window_end_idx)//2
        
        for i in range(window_begin_idx, window_end_idx+1):
            
            number = closing_price[i]
            
            if number < mins:
                mins=number
                min_idx = np.where(closing_price==mins)[0][0]
            if number > maxs:
                maxs=number
                max_idx = np.where(closing_price==maxs)[0][0]

        if max_idx == window_middle_idx:
            result.append("SELL")
        elif min_idx == window_middle_idx:
            result.append("BUY")
        else:
            result.append("HOLD")
        
        mins = 10000.0
        maxs = 0.0
        
    counter+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `mins, maxs, min_idx and max_idx` with appropriate values before the main loop.

In your case `if max_idx ==` occurs earlier than any `max_idx` assignment

Edit after questing change:

Seems in Python you can make similar behavior replacing the whole for-loop with:

```
 rng = closing_price[window_begin_idx:window_end_idx+1]
 mins = rng.min()
 maxs = rng.max()
 min_idx = rng.index(mins)
 max_idx = rng.index(maxs)
```

Comment: That's strange, I thought that little `for loop` would get executed first before reaching the `max_idx` stage and that `for loop` is to get the `mins, max, min_idx, and max_id` from the window. I'm not sure what values to initialize for them. What do you think?

Comment: Note that min_idx and max_id are assigned only inside conditional operator `if`. Error text shows us that you reached `if max_idx == ` but `if number > maxs:` has not occured yet.

Comment: yea, agree with you there. I actually found the author's implementation in JAVA which I don't particularly understand well, but still managed to get rid of the error but now only `else` clause in the end is getting met and returning **HOLD** values for all the rows. I'm editing my question so let me know if you can suggest anything. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: But you still violate logic. As far as I understand, `mins = rng.min()` finds minumum in the some subarray. So `if number < mins:` never occurs for the same subarray, doesn't it? Article code is straightforward - it just searches minimum and maximum in the window and remembers corresponding indices. Look at my edit

Comment: Hey man, thanks a lot for your help. I have actually managed to figure it out. I was making some stupid mistakes and your suggestions did help :)